# Random Walks- Stochastic Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Suppose a random walk on $S = \{0, 1, 2, \dots , 5\}$ defined as follows. If $1 ≤ k ≤ 4$ and
$X_n = k$, then $X_{n+1}$ is $k ± 1$ each with probability 1/2. If $X_n = 0$, then $X_{n+1} = 0$
(0 is absorbing). If $X_n = 5$, then $X_{n+1}$ is either 5 or 4, each with probability 1/2
(5 is "retaining"). Let $T = \min\{n ≥ 0 : X_n = 0\}$ denote the time that the walk
gets absorbed at 0. For each k with 0 ≤ k ≤ 5, determine $τ(k) = E[T|\ X_0 = k]$. (E.g.,
τ(0) = 0.)

Comment: Can you tell what part you find difficult? Generally you will want to write equations for $\tau_k$ in terms of themselves. We have $\tau_k=1+r_k$ where $r_k$ is the expected remaining time after the first step from state $k$.

Comment: First step analysis, read it up from whichever textbook you are referring to, and there will surely be a worked example.

Answer (score 0):

Let the probability of moving to the right be $p$ and the probability of moving to the left be $1-p$ (in the case of state $5$, the probability of remaining in state $5$ is $p$). We have the system of linear equations
\begin{align}
\tau(0) &= 0\\
\tau(1) &= 1 + (1-p)\tau(0) + p\tau(2)\\
\tau(2) &= 1 + (1-p)\tau(1) + p\tau(3)\\
\tau(3) &= 1 + (1-p)\tau(2) + p\tau(4)\\
\tau(4) &= 1 + (1-p)\tau(3) + p\tau(5)\\
\tau(5) &= 1 + (1-p)\tau(4) + p\tau(5)
\end{align}
which yields the unique solution
\begin{align}
\tau(0) &= 0\\
\tau(1) &= \frac{p^4-2 p^3+4 p^2-3 p+1}{(1-p)^5}\\
\tau(2) &= \frac{p^4-4 p^3+8 p^2-6 p+2}{(1-p)^5}\\
\tau(3) &= \frac{2 p^4-7 p^3+12 p^2-9 p+3}{(1-p)^5}\\
\tau(4) &= \frac{2 p^4-8 p^3+15 p^2-12 p+4}{(1-p)^5}\\
\tau(5) &= \frac{3 p^4-12 p^3+21 p^2-16 p+5}{(1-p)^5}.
\end{align}